# How to serialize a JObject without the formatting?

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I have a `JObject` (I'm using Json.Net) that I constructed with LINQ to JSON (also provided by the same library).  When I call the `ToString()` method on the `JObject`, it outputs the results as formatted JSON.

How do I set the formatting to "none" for this?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Call JObject's `ToString(Formatting.None)` method.

Alternatively if you pass the object to the JsonConvert.SerializeObject method it will return the JSON without formatting.

Documentation: [**Write JSON text with JToken.ToString**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ToString.htm)

Comment: Does that mean that passing a `JObject` to `SerializeObject` is a special case?  Instead of treating the `JObject` as an ordinary C# class and trying to serialise the internals, it does something like `jObject.ToString(...)` instead?

Answer (score 52):

You can also do the following;

```
string json = myJObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

Comment: How is this any different from the James' suggestion above? James did not include the full namespace reference and you did--otherwise the code is the same, no?

Comment: @Jazimov They are the same. It's because James' answer was edited in 2014. When Simpu posted this answer back in 2010 the earlier post by James was about SerializeObject and not the formatting parameter of ToString() (you can see this in the edit history of the answer).

Answer (score 22):

you can use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject) // myObject is returned by JObject.Parse() method
```

[JsonConvert.SerializeObject()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)

[JObject.Parse()](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)