# How to write the value of one json property in one line?

Tags: c#, json, jsonparser

It is necessary to write value of "Coordinates" property in json without hyphenation for the following lines, not using ToString() (without converting the value to a string). The desired result is shown below.

```
{
          "Id": null,
          "Style": "1234",
          "Geometry": {
            "Type": "Polygon",
            "Coordinates": [[[47541.470259278358,6846.8710054924586],[47540.359922950891,6845.4552435801925],[47541.470259278358,6846.8710054924586]]],
            "Properties": [
              {
                "PointType": "Straight"
              },
              {
                "PointType": "Straight"
              },
              {
                "PointType": "Straight"
              }
            ]
       }
}
```

but not:

```
{
          "Id": null,
          "Style": "1234",
          "Geometry": {
            "Type": "Polygon",
            "Coordinates": "[[[47541.470259278358,6846.8710054924586],[47540.359922950891,6845.4552435801925],[47541.470259278358,6846.8710054924586]]]",
            "Properties": [
              {
                "PointType": "Straight"
              },
              {
                "PointType": "Straight"
              },
              {
                "PointType": "Straight"
              }
            ]
       }
}
```

A function that serializes the corresponding class object in json:

```cs
JToken ToJson()
        {
            using (var writer = new JTokenWriter()) {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
                return writer.Token;
            }
        }
```

Comment: By "one line", do you mean one line of C# code or one line of JSON?

Comment: one line of JSON

Comment: Please provide us some line of codes and tell us which parser do you use for the serialization.

Comment: Whitespace in JSON does not matter, so whether the nested array is printed on one line or multiple lines, from the point of view of the parser/writer, the JSON is still the same JSON. Just write the JSON normally. You just need a custom way of printing your JSON out.

Comment: By default, the json is displayed with the line-break of each sub-array and cells to a new one on the following lines. Is it possible to remove hyphens for a particular property ("Coordinates")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems your second case contains Coordinates property as serialized string.

why should not use 
`var string = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject)`  ?

But you should install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ first

You could use string  type for properties where you need double quotes and use array or number if you don't need it

Comment: Exactly. It is not good for me. To write the value of the property in one line, it is suggested to convert the value into a string (as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570689/how-to-serialize-a-jobject-without-the-formatting/572076). But I need to achieve a result without converting value of property to a string.

Comment: How is your Coordinates property presented in c# class  ? List<List<List<Int>>> ?

Comment: Yes, List<List<List<double>>>

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YourObject) returns  desired result, or I am something missed ?

Comment: So he write json at all without line-breaks. I will try in this case to add line-breaks everywhere except "Coordinates".

Comment: there is my result string "{"id":null,"data":[[[10.0,11.0]]]}" without line-breaks.

Comment: Ah I guess you meant double quotes instead line-breaks. For string properties it  is always value in double quotes in json string result. For number types for example it is without quotes at all and  the same for arrays.

Comment: I want to ensure that there are no quotes in the "Coordinates" property value (because it is an array) and there are no line-breaks between subarrays. For example: "Coordinates" : [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]].  But by default json separates subarrays with line-breaks. This can be fixed by converting the value of Coordinates property to a string, BUT is it possible to fix it in another way without converting to a string?

Comment: I have not seen any line -breaks on json string "{"Test":null,"Data":[[[10.0,11.0],[14.0,17.0]]]}". But ok you could convert Coordinates  array  to string and after that  deserialize main object and manually deserialize Coordinates property too. But Could you explain me how you got line-breaks between sub-arrays ?

Comment: When I wrote an object serialized in json: Console.WriteLine(obj.ToJson()); (the ToJson() function code is given in the question). All properties and sub-properties are automatically separated by line-breaks. But I understand you, I will try to do as you said, thanks.

Comment: I got it you are using different JsonSerializer, could you use Newtonsoft.Json instead  ? it works without redundant line-breaks and other stuff. Also you could try to use Console.WriteLine(obj.ToJson().toString())

Comment: Because your application console  shows  not string but JToken value