# JObject formatting list issue

Tags: c#, json, collections, json.net

I have an issue with the `JObject.ToString()` method. I am trying to save the object data in a JSON file. The problem here is, I kind of want to use a mix between `Formatting.None` and `Formatting.Indented`. I want to print every item in a new row, but if there is a list, I want the list values in one row only and not for each item a new line.

The format should look like this:

```
{
  "Vector": [1,2,3,4,5]
  "Name": null
}
```

Currently, if I use `Formatting.None` I get this:

```
{"Vector":[1,2,3,4,5],"Name":null}
```

And if I use `Formatting.Indented`, I get this:

```
{
  "Vector": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  ],
  "Name": null
}
```

Is there a way to use `Formatting.None` only for lists and `Formatting.Indented` for every other data type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply indenting serialization only to some properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655996/how-to-apply-indenting-serialization-only-to-some-properties)

Comment: [How to apply indenting serialization only to some properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28655996/3744182) and [Newtonsoft inline formatting for subelement while serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30831895/3744182) would appear to be duplicates for this question (though not your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65304693/3744182)) since the problem here involves changing the formatting during serialization rather than during `JToken` writing.